# How to calculate data from database in current month from first date of month until current date in month

Tags: php, html, mysql

The problem for this code is it calculate all data from all month that has in the database.. It not from this current month from first date of this month until current date of this month...Can someone help me...

```
<tbody>
    <?php
                                    
      $FullTotal = 0;
      while($rowF = $resultX -> fetch_assoc()){// registerfighter
          $totalPlus = 0;
          //table start
    ?> 
    <tr> 
       <td><?php echo $rowF["UserName"] ?></td>  
       <?php
            $resultY-> data_seek(0);
            while($rowY = $resultY -> fetch_assoc()){ // by addplan
                $resultR -> data_seek(0);
                while($rowR = $resultR -> fetch_assoc()){ // by record
                    if ($first_date <= $rowR["SubmitDate"]  && $last_date <= $rowR["SubmitDate"]){
                    // this the problems...it not work
                        if( ($rowF["UserID"]===$rowR["UserIDD"])  and
                            (($rowR["No_Plan"]) === '1' and 
                            ($rowY["No_Plan"] === $rowR['No_Plan']))) {
                                $total = ($rowR["UserInputNEW"] + $rowR["UserInputNMP"]);
                                $totalPlus = $totalPlus + $total;
                                $FullTotal = $FullTotal + $total;
                          }
                    }
               }
          }
      ?> 
         <td><?php echo $totalPlus; ?></td>
     </tr> 
     <?php
         //table end
      } ?>
         <td colspan="1"> Total  </td> 
         <td colspan="1"> <?php echo $FullTotal?></td> 
   </tbody>
```

Comment: One of your `if` conditions contains `&&` while another `if` contains `and`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: SQL is pretty good at aggregating and adding up. That way you don't need to write code for it. Can you [provide a minimal example of your data structure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)?